# Is there an API that can be used to programitically regenerate previews

Tags: content, contentdocument

I need to regenerate an unknown number of file previews.  I have not found anything in the documentation so far.  Does the Apex API support this?  Really don't want to use the online "Regenerate a Content or File Preview" individually.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce support confirmed that at present there is no option to programmatically regenerate the previews.

I was able to generate a Selenium script that iterated through all of my contentversionids and submit each one individually using the "Regenerate a Content or File Preview" page.